# NLog windows application log files not created after make an installable exe

Tags: c#, nlog, windows

I have created a windows application and log the error files in text files,when i published and make it as an application files, the log files is not created in the respective folder.

working fine- before convert into setup , the problem happens after installable exe.
can anyone suggest to do a better solution
app.config

```
 <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/DebugLog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-logFile.log" />
```

added the nlog elements in app config

```
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/DebugLog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-logFile.log" />

   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

C#:

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                logger.Error("Some Error has occured ");
        }
```

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/DebugLog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-logFile.log" />



    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>


  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show your nlog config. Does you configured path exists? Do you see the internal logfile?

Comment: Probably there is no rights to write to requested directory. NLog has a lot of try/catch, that's why I don't recommend to use it - it just does not throw exceptions if it fails to log something (not always, but still)

Comment: @tester when i have run the files inside visual studio , it has created and when i have run the bin exe files it has logs the file, after make it as the executable installable file it has not created.No folder not created log files also not created.

Comment: How do you load the nlog.config?

Comment: @Tester  have added the configuration in app.config after respective packages has added.

Comment: Best way is to show all code which contains nlog stuff

Comment: @i have updated the code,the log has created in debug mode ,after publish and created an executable files it is not created bin\Debug\DebugLog

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy you could easily configure that behavior.

Comment: @MohamedSahir: Add the following to your nlog.config:      internalLogLevel="trace"
      internalLogFile="log/internal-nlog.txt"
      throwExceptions="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"  so you should see erro inside log/internal-nlog.txt

Comment: @tester where it will generate the log file after  running the installable file

Comment: @MohamedSahir next to your dll there should be a log directory in the case you take my config

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is a bad copy-paste job, but you have invalid xml:

```
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/DebugLog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-logFile.log" />

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Should be changed to (include end-targets-tag):

```
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/DebugLog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-logFile.log" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="email" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

But good idea to enable and check the internal logger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging